# CA-group [abelian centralizer group]

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

I am searching for all information about **CA-groups** [abelian centralizer group] and i just found a German book [ Huppert ] and Nilpotent Centralizer group of Suzuki in 44 pages.

I need more English books and thesis or journal having this title.Where can i find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the wiki page on CA-groups? There are a few references included on the page that you have not mentioned.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA-group